# std::vector insert() reallocation

Tags: c++, stdvector

I was looking through the std::vector code and I found something I didn't quite get. When capacity < size() + 1 it needs to reallocate the buffer so it can insert the new element. What it does (as far as I've been able to extract from the code) is:

- allocate the new buffer
- copy the prefix of the old buffer (0 - index of insertion)
- construct the new element in the new buffer
- copy the suffix of the old buffer (index - end)
- **call destructor on all items in old buffer**
- deallocate old buffer

The prefix and suffix copy is done with memmove as far as I could see. Isn't memmove a pure binary copy of the data? It doesn't call the constructor of the elements, does it? What I was wondering is, why does the function call the destructor on the elements in the old buffer if the memory is just moved, not re-constructed in the new buffer?

Comment: I think your understanding of the code is wrong. If you think memmove is being used, please post  a fragment that illustrates this.

Comment: Using memmove is a potential optimization of the compiler. But its us is only valid for POD types. If the type has a constructor/destructor they need to be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked through the MSVC8 `vector` implementation - I can't see a `memmove()`. The previous vector elements are  not moved, they're copied and their copy c'tor is called to copy them over to the new buffer (the buffer is allocated in a single allocation, elements are constructed using placement new).

Of course this is only the MSVC implementation, but it's how a `vector` should behave according to the standard.

However, using `memmove` is sometimes OK - for example for a `std::vector<int>` - and STL implementations are free to specialize for this case. You might have missed a template 'branch' reading the source code.

Comment: Yes, I did. I was seeing the <int> specialization. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if it would be equally valid to `swap(old, new)` instead of constructing and destructing.

Comment: I don't think `swap` is valid because it requires `old` and `new` to be fully constructed, which isn't the case with the destination buffer. With C++11, `std::move` instead of `std::copy` is ok, though.